# persistence.CordaPersistence. - Cleanup task failed: [errorCode=1d5efik, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.4/1d5efik]

Tags: kotlin, liquibase, corda, discord

I've been trying to launch Corda flow tests for almost a week now, without any success. Unfortunately, there's little information on StachOverflow about enything on Corda. So my tests didn't want to launch and I decided to analize node logs from test/logs folder.

This is what I've found

```
[INFO ] 2020-06-18T10:26:32,940Z [main] internal.InternalMockNetwork$MockNode. - Node starting up ... {}
  [INFO ] 2020-06-18T10:26:33,251Z [main] internal.InternalMockNetwork$MockNode. - Loaded network 
  parameters: NetworkParameters {
  minimumPlatformVersion=1
  notaries=[NotaryInfo(identity=O=Notary Service, L=Zurich, C=CH, validating=true)]
  maxMessageSize=10485760
  maxTransactionSize=524288000
  whitelistedContractImplementations {
    
  }
  eventHorizon=PT720H
  packageOwnership {
    
  }
  modifiedTime=2020-06-18T10:26:19.392Z
  epoch=1
} 
 [INFO ] 2020-06-18T10:26:39,764Z [main] persistence.AttachmentVersionNumberMigration. - Start 
         executing... {changeSet=migration/node-services.changelog-init.xml::update-version-of- 
         whitelisted- 
         jars::R3.Corda, databaseChangeLog=master.changelog.json}
 [INFO ] 2020-06-18T10:26:39,781Z [main] persistence.AttachmentVersionNumberMigration. - Attachment 
         version creation from whitelisted JARs using network parameters from build\mock- 
         network\20200618- 
         102619.443\nodes\0\network-parameters, whitelistedContractImplementations: {}. 
         {changeSet=migration/node-services.changelog-init.xml::update-version-of-whitelisted- 
         jars::R3.Corda, 
         databaseChangeLog=master.changelog.json}
 [INFO ] 2020-06-18T10:26:39,781Z [main] persistence.AttachmentVersionNumberMigration. - Attachment 
         version creation from whitelisted JARs skipped, no attachments not found. 
         {changeSet=migration/node- 
         services.changelog-init.xml::update-version-of-whitelisted-jars::R3.Corda, 
         databaseChangeLog=master.changelog.json}
 [INFO ] 2020-06-18T10:26:39,898Z [main] migration.VaultStateMigration. - Migrating vault state data 
         to V4 tables {changeSet=migration/vault-schema.changelog-v9.xml::update-vault- 
         states::R3.Corda, 
         databaseChangeLog=master.changelog.json}
 [INFO ] 2020-06-18T10:26:40,011Z [main] persistence.HibernateConfiguration. - Init 
         HibernateConfiguration for schemas: 
         [VaultMigrationSchemaV1(name=net.corda.node.migration.VaultMigrationSchema, version=1), 
         VaultSchemaV1(name=net.corda.node.services.vault.VaultSchema, version=1)] 
         {changeSet=migration/vault-schema.changelog-v9.xml::update-vault-states::R3.Corda, 
         databaseChangeLog=master.changelog.json}
 [INFO ] 2020-06-18T10:26:40,026Z [main] persistence.HibernateConfiguration. - Creating session 
         factory for schemas: 
         [VaultMigrationSchemaV1(name=net.corda.node.migration.VaultMigrationSchema, 
         version=1), VaultSchemaV1(name=net.corda.node.services.vault.VaultSchema, version=1)] 
         {changeSet=migration/vault-schema.changelog-v9.xml::update-vault-states::R3.Corda, 
         databaseChangeLog=master.changelog.json}
 [WARN ] 2020-06-18T10:26:42,142Z [main] persistence.CordaPersistence. - Cleanup task failed: 
         [errorCode=1d5efik, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.4/1d5efik] 
         {changeSet=migration/vault-schema.changelog-v9.xml::update-vault-states::R3.Corda, 
         databaseChangeLog=master.changelog.json}
         java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection$ClosedConnection.lambda$getClosedConnection$0(ProxyConnection.java:493) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar:?]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(ProxyConnection.java:392) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar:?]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.DatabaseTransaction$connection$2.invoke(DatabaseTransaction.kt:30) ~[corda-node-api-4.4.jar:?]
at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.DatabaseTransaction$connection$2.invoke(DatabaseTransaction.kt:21) ~[corda-node-api-4.4.jar:?]
at kotlin.UnsafeLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:81) ~[kotlin-stdlib-1.3.71.jar:1.3.71-release-431 (1.3.71)]
at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.DatabaseTransaction.getConnection(DatabaseTransaction.kt) ~[corda-node-api-4.4.jar:?]
at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.DatabaseTransaction.rollback(DatabaseTransaction.kt:86) ~[corda-node-api-4.4.jar:?]
at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence$inTopLevelTransaction$2.invoke(CordaPersistence.kt:277) ~[corda-node-api-4.4.jar:?]
at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence$inTopLevelTransaction$2.invoke(CordaPersistence.kt:96) ~[corda-node-api-4.4.jar:?]
at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence$inTopLevelTransaction$1.invoke(CordaPersistence.kt:266) ~[corda-node-api-4.4.jar:?]
at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.inTopLevelTransaction(CordaPersistence.kt:277) ~[corda-node-api-4.4.jar:?]
at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:249) ~[corda-node-api-4.4.jar:?]
at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:215) ~[corda-node-api-4.4.jar:?]
at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:221) ~[corda-node-api-4.4.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.migration.CordaMigration.initialiseNodeServices(CordaMigration.kt:65) ~[corda-node-4.4.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.migration.VaultStateMigration.execute(VaultStateMigration.kt:77) ~[corda-node-4.4.jar:?]
at liquibase.change.custom.CustomChangeWrapper.generateStatements(CustomChangeWrapper.java:183) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.3.jar:?]
at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1209) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.3.jar:?]
at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:600) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.3.jar:?]
at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:53) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.3.jar:?]
at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:83) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.3.jar:?]
at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:202) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.3.jar:?]
at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:179) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.3.jar:?]
at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:175) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.3.jar:?]
at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.SchemaMigration.doRunMigration(SchemaMigration.kt:143) ~[corda-node-api-4.4.jar:?]
at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.SchemaMigration.runMigration(SchemaMigration.kt:70) ~[corda-node-api-4.4.jar:?]
at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.SchemaMigration.nodeStartup(SchemaMigration.kt:61) ~[corda-node-api-4.4.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNodeKt.startHikariPool(AbstractNode.kt:1279) ~[corda-node-4.4.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.startDatabase(AbstractNode.kt:922) ~[corda-node-4.4.jar:?]
at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork$MockNode.startDatabase(InternalMockNetwork.kt:406) ~[corda-node-driver-4.4.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.start(AbstractNode.kt:473) ~[corda-node-4.4.jar:?]
at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork$MockNode.start(InternalMockNetwork.kt:347) ~[corda-node-driver-4.4.jar:?]
at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.createNodeImpl(InternalMockNetwork.kt:472) ~[corda-node-driver-4.4.jar:?]
at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.createNode(InternalMockNetwork.kt:450) ~[corda-node-driver-4.4.jar:?]
at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.createNode(InternalMockNetwork.kt:445) ~[corda-node-driver-4.4.jar:?]
at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.createNotaries$node_driver(InternalMockNetwork.kt:254) ~[corda-node-driver-4.4.jar:?]
at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.<init>(InternalMockNetwork.kt:237) ~[corda-node-driver-4.4.jar:?]
at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.<init>(InternalMockNetwork.kt:150) ~[corda-node-driver-4.4.jar:?]
at net.corda.testing.node.MockNetwork.<init>(MockNetwork.kt:305) ~[corda-node-driver-4.4.jar:?]
at net.corda.testing.node.MockNetwork.<init>(MockNetwork.kt:294) ~[corda-node-driver-4.4.jar:?]
at net.corda.testing.node.MockNetwork.<init>(MockNetwork.kt:303) ~[corda-node-driver-4.4.jar:?]
at com.sentinel.flows.SharedInformationFlowTests.setup(SharedInformationFlowTests.kt:32) ~[test/:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110) ~[?:?]
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58) ~[?:?]
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38) ~[?:?]
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62) ~[?:?]
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51) ~[?:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35) ~[gradle-tooling-api-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24) ~[gradle-tooling-api-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32) ~[?:?]
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93) ~[gradle-tooling-api-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:118) ~[?:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35) ~[gradle-tooling-api-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24) ~[gradle-tooling-api-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:175) ~[?:?]
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:157) ~[?:?]
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404) ~[?:?]
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63) ~[gradle-tooling-api-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46) ~[gradle-tooling-api-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55) ~[gradle-tooling-api-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_251]
```

Comment: Is there any logs with [ERROR] tag? I suppose this is not the full log which is not possible to narrow down the cause of the problem

Comment: Hi! There's nothing with error tag, but there's a stacktrace below. I've added it fyi.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to our docs and try to run the tests in this cordapp: https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/tree/master/Basic/cordapp-example

The sample has a couple of runConfiguration. I think it will be helpful for us to know if you can run these runConfigutations, in order to further help you.

When you open intelliJ, you should look for the top right for the runConfiguration:
[image]